# SFTP using jschexception verify false sometimes fails

Tags: jsch

We are getting **jcraft.jsch.JSchException: verify: false** while getting the ChannelSftp. Now a days it is occurring very frequently.

Below is my environment where I am getting this error.

`java version "1.7.0_10" and 1.7.0_13`

`weblogic 11g(10.3.6.0)`

`jsch jar version jsch-0.1.50.jar`

any suggestions on how to resolve this issue are much helpful.

## Here is my block of code that I have used for getting channel

```
ChannelSftp sftpChannel = null;
JSch jsch = new JSch();

Properties jschConfig = new Properties();

jschConfig.setProperty("compression.s2c", "none");
jschConfig.setProperty("compression.c2s", "none");
jschConfig.setProperty("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
jschConfig.setProperty("PreferredAuthentications", "publickey,password");
JSch.setConfig(jschConfig);

Session session = null;
try {
    jsch.removeAllIdentity();

    jsch.addIdentity(privateKeyFile);

    session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);

    session.connect();

} catch (JSchException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed to connect to " + host, e);
}

sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
sftpChannel.connect();
```